# Python re.sub behaves differently than re.findall

Tags: python

I'm stumped. I'm coding Python 3.6.2, using PyCharm as my IDE. The following script fragment illustrates my problem:

```
def dosubst(m):
    return m.group() + "X"

line = r"set @message = formatmessage('%s %s', @arg1, @arg2);"
m = re.findall(r"@\w+\b", line, re.IGNORECASE)
print(m[0])  # prints "@message"
print(m[1])  # prints "@arg1"
print(m[2])  # prints "@arg2"

foo = re.sub(r"@\w+\b", dosubst, line, re.IGNORECASE)
print(foo)  # prints "set @messageX = formatmessage('%s %s', @arg1X, @arg2);"
```

You can see that `re.findall` finds three matches. However, `re.sub` only calls the `dosubst` function **twice**. If I change `@message` to `message` then `re.sub` still calls `dosubst` twice, but picks up `@arg1` and `@arg2`. Baffled. I thought it might be greedy vs. posessive, etc. but - changing `@message` to `message` and the resulting behavior negates that. Can anyone explain? I'm trying to do some basic text parsing of SQL to refactor message formatting for a large number of files. I use regexr.com to prototype most of the regex stuff I do and it also finds three occurrences of the pattern in the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).  The fourth argument to `re.sub` is `count`, not `flags`.  Since `re.IGNORECASE` happens to be 2, you are telling it to only do two substitutions.  Instead, pass `flags` by keyword:

```
>>> re.sub(r"@\w+\b", dosubst, line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
"set @messageX = formatmessage('%s %s', @arg1X, @arg2X);"
```

Answer (score 0):

By giving the fourth argument `count=0`. If you put the other positive numbers instead of `0` than it will replace the string exactly the same number of time.

```
foo = re.sub(r"@\w+\b", dosubst, line, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
print(foo)
```

output:

```
"set @MessageX = formatmessage('%s %s', @arg1X, @arg2X);"
```